# multiline form qty totals javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a 9 line form that has 3 fields each QTY, Number of times used & Total 
using java script I was about to get the first field to populate the total correctly but I need to know how do the same math on the additional 8 lines.

Simply put it's (qty x nos = total) for every line.

Here is the code used for the first line :

```
function calculatePrice(){
    //Get selected data  
    var qty = document.getElementById("QTYps1").value;
    var nos = document.getElementById("numbofs1").value;
    //convert data to integers
    qty = parseInt(qty);
    nos = parseInt(nos);
    //calculate total value  
    var total = qty * nos;
    //print value to total 
    document.getElementById("totalQTY1").value=total;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you have your fields declared with incrementing id's. Try this code below:

```
function calculatePrice(){
  for (var i=1; i<20;i++){
    if (document.getElementById("QTYps"+i)){ // check it exists
      //Get selected data  
      var qty = document.getElementById("QTYps"+i).value;
      var nos = document.getElementById("numbofs"+i).value;
      //convert data to integers
      qty = parseInt(qty);
      nos = parseInt(nos);
      //calculate total value  
     var total = qty * nos;
     //print value to total 
      document.getElementById("totalQTY"+i).value=total;
    }
  }
}
```